# symfony2 : How to disable APC cache selectively on few routes

Tags: symfony, caching, apc

I am using symfony version 2.3 . I have used following in my config.yml

```
metadata_cache_driver: apc
result_cache_driver: apc
query_cache_driver: apc
```

I want to disable caching at following URL . www.domain.com/dashboard

How can I achieve this ? Any help

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information of why you want to do that?

Comment: As soon as I submit any form to Edit , Symfony somehow not recognizing new values and submit it with old values.
However it works absolutely fine with APC disabled. I want to handle my admin CMS without APC for same reason

Comment: I think this is not related to APC. Usually, if the form is not valid, symfony2 renders the same content. Have you check the form errors?

Comment: Yes , did this for sure , have written all validations inside if (Form isvalid) block. 
May be I am missing something but if without APC it is working fine , It has to do something with APC only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `app.php` or `index.php` you should have something like this :

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
$loader->unregister();
$apcLoader->register(true);

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// ...
```

so you can have a condition with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

e.g

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

if (!preg_match('#dashboard#'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    $apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
    $loader->unregister();
    $apcLoader->register(true);

    require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

    $kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
}

// ...
```

hope it helps

Comment: How would it actually work then ?  I feel it is something at global level , I need it at route level , For this matter if it is just a user level , I am okay with it

Comment: you could use an event listener on kernel.request to change the container parameter dynamically

Comment: Worked like charm , Thanks Buddy !!

Comment: @vishalvasudeva with or without listener ?